# TypeError: navigation.getChildNavigation is not a function. (In 'navigation.getChildNavigation(route.key)'

Tags: redux, react-native, react-navigation, redux-thunk

I wanted to integrate Redux with React-navigation. Created all the structure for the implementation. But, I am getting the above error and I am getting no any proper solution. I found some similar error raised by others , but non helped me.
The structure of my project is:

```
index.js
src=>
   actions=>
   reducers=>
     index.js
     loginReducers.js
     navigationReducer.js
   route=>
     InitialAuthRoute.js
     ReduxNavigation.js
   screens=>
     Login.js
```

index.js

```
  import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
  import ReduxNavigation from './src/route/ReduxNavigation';
  import {name as appName} from './app.json';
  import React from 'react';
  import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
  import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
  import reducers from './src/reducers';
  import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

  const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

  const AppContainer = () =>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReduxNavigation/>
    </Provider>

  AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppContainer);
```

ReduxNavigation.js

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import { addNavigationHelpers } from "react-navigation";
  import InitialAuthRoute from "./InitialAuthRoute";
  import NavigationReducer from "../reducers/navigationReducer";

  class AppNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <InitialAuthRoute navigation={({
          dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
          state: this.props.navigationState,
        })} />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      navigationState: state.nav
    };
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppNavigation);
```

initialAuthRoute.js

```
  import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
  import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login'

  const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen }
  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
  })

  export default PrimaryNav
```

reducers/index.js

```
  import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
  import LoginReducers from './loginReducers';
  import NavigationReducer from "./navigationReducer";

  export default combineReducers({
    login: LoginReducers,
    nav: NavigationReducer,
  })
```

navigationReducer:

```
  import AppNavigator from "../route/InitialAuthRoute";

  const navigationReducer = (state, action) => {

    const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return newState || state;
  };

  export default navigationReducer;
```

Environment:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 3.27 GB / 7.92 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.3.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.16.0 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.4.0.0 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156

Packages:
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^3.0.2",
```